# Converting main() into a daemon thread possible

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, program-entry-point

As per my knowledge `main()` in Java is a non daemon thread by default, so is it possible to convert it into a daemon thread?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this?

Comment: No... not exactly just was asked to me in a exam

Comment: What I would have answered:  (A) the program must have at least one non-daemon thread in order to keep running, and (B) The identity of threads is never important: If I want a daemon thread, I can start one, and if I don't want main() to keep running, I can let it terminate.

Comment: _that mean you always require a non daemon thread_...?  In fact, that is the _only_ significance of daemon vs. non-daemon.  Non-daemon threads keep the JVM alive, and daemon threads don't.  There is no other difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are only daemon threads running then the JVM will shutdown. If the main thread was a daemon thread then the program couldn't run without shutting down right away. Also you're not allowed to set the daemon property on a thread after it's started, you can't change a non-daemon thread to a daemon thread while it's running:

> public final void setDaemon(boolean on)
>
> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java
>   Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon
>   threads.
>
> This method must be invoked before the thread is started.

Comment: ohh!! thank you. that mean you always require a non daemon thread so that any daemon thread can run.

Comment: @gaurav: yes for the program to run you have to have at least one non-daemon thread. which might as well be the main thread.